# Convert this SQL into eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I want to convert the following sql statement into eloquent:

```
select order_number, order_id, sum(quantity) as qty, sum(price) as pr from `orders` right join `order_details` on `orders`.`id` = `order_details`.`order_id` group by `order_number`
```

I did this as like below:

```
$order = OrderDetails::select(DB::raw('order_number, order_id, sum(quantity) as qty, sum(price) as pr'))
            ->from('orders')    
            ->rightJoin('order_details', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_details.order_id')
            ->groupBy('order_number')
            ->get();
dd($order);
```

The problem is that it is converting to the same sql but showing error. The error is shown below:
*

> ```
> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'techvillege.order_details.order_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select
> ```
>
> order_number, order_id, sum(quantity) as qty, sum(price) as pr from
>   `orders` right join `order_details` on `orders`.`id` =
>   `order_details`.`order_id` group by `order_number`)

*
The tables are:
[orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gVFb.png)
[order_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGSWs.png)
I really do not know what is the exact problem here and stuck into it for the last two days. Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says that u need to add `order_id` to `groupBy()` method

```
$order = OrderDetails::select(DB::raw('order_number, order_id, sum(quantity) as qty, sum(price) as pr'))
            ->from('orders')    
            ->rightJoin('order_details', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_details.order_id')
            ->groupBy('order_number', 'order_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: That solved the problem perfectly but can you please explain why should I do that? Cause I wanted to group by order_number, not order_id

Comment: If u use aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, AVG...),  all fields in `select()` method, must be included in `group by`